# new Date() parsing compatibility

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a string into a `Date` object and it looks like there is a lot of cross browser compatibility issue around this.

My string is simple "2016-1-11 10:30". Code is also simple

```
var d = new Date(str);
```

Firefox and Chrome are both happy this format but Safari refuse to turn it into an valid object.

Is there a way or a javascript library that iron this out?

Comment: Library requests are offtopic for SO, but the usual goto library for this sort of stuff is [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). As for your underlying issue - yes, what you're passing in is "non-standard" as far as the spec is concerned, so implementations are free to interpret it (or not) how they choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: What's about this `2016-01-11 10:30:00`?

Comment: @Tresdin That's an improvement, but it doesn't strictly match [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (there's no `T`), so browsers could still technically do what they like.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Ahha, that's a MySQL one. Thanks for the hint. It should be `2016-01-11T03:30:00.000Z`. That's why I prefer storing datetime in number `1452483000000`.

Answer (score -2):

Safari hates using hyphens for date delimiters.

Try the following code to replace them with slashes

```
var d = new Date(str.replace(/-/g, "/")));
```

it will replace all occurrences of - with a forward slash and reformat your date to: 2016/1/11 10:30. This should keep Safari sufficiently happy but may have other implications on your code if you rely on the hyphen format.

Answer (score -2):

As @James Thorpe said moment.js is the way to go.
If you cant by any chance include moment.js then the standard format here should be `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`

Chrome and Firefox will forgive you for that but all browsers wont.